# Get the unique occurrences of multiple columns permutation in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, unique, permutation

I have a pandas dataframe with multiple columns, two of those columns can potentially contain permutted data (`SOMMET_1`, `SOMMET_2` in the following example).

An sample of the dataframe is:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[2017, 'MTEZ5P71', 'MTEZIP71', 0.395508, 5.078320],
                   [2017, 'MTEZ5P71', 'RUEYRP71', 0.395508, 5.078320],
                   [2022, 'MTEZ5P71', 'RUEYRP71', 0.006328, 25.435898],     
                   [2022, 'RUEYRP71', 'MTEZ5P71', 0.006328, 25.435898],
                   [2022, 'ARGIAP71', '.HERN 71', 1.180195, 12.507539]],
                  columns=['YEAR', 'SOMMET_1', 'SOMMET_2', 'R', 'X'])
```

| **YEAR** | **SOMMET_1** | **SOMMET_2** | **R** | **X** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2017 | MTEZ5P71 | MTEZIP71 | 0.395508 | 5.078320 |
| 2017 | MTEZ5P71 | RUEYRP71 | 0.395508 | 5.078320 |
| 2022 | MTEZ5P71 | RUEYRP71 | 0.006328 | 25.435898 |
| 2022 | RUEYRP71 | MTEZ5P71 | 0.006328 | 25.435898 |
| 2022 | ARGIAP71 | .HERN 71 | 1.180195 | 12.507539 |

For each value in `YEAR`, I'm trying to get only the rows with unique occurences of the unordered permutations of the data in both columns [`SOMMET_1`, `SOMMET_2`]. Ideally ordered in alphabetical order from column `SOMMET_1`.

The expected result shall be the original dataframe **ONLY** with unique pairs `SOMMET_1` and `SOMMET_2` for a given `YEAR`. For the example above, the dataframe shall not contain the fourth row:

| **YEAR** | **SOMMET_1** | **SOMMET_2** | **R** | **X** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2017 | MTEZ5P71 | MTEZIP71 | 0.395508 | 5.078320 |
| 2017 | MTEZ5P71 | RUEYRP71 | 0.395508 | 5.078320 |
| 2022 | MTEZ5P71 | RUEYRP71 | 0.006328 | 25.435898 |
| 2022 | ARGIAP71 | .HERN 71 | 1.180195 | 12.507539 |

I've tried to use the `groupby` method.

```
df.groupby(['SOMMET_1', 'SOMMET_2'])['YEAR']
```

But it does not warrant that a sub-group under `SOMMET_2` is not repeated in `SOMMET_1` sub-group.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this. Find the unique pairs and then groupby:

```
def get_unique_pairs(df):
    unique_pairs = set(tuple(sorted([row.SOMMET_1, row.SOMMET_2])) for _, row in df.iterrows())
    return df[df.apply(lambda row: tuple(sorted([row.SOMMET_1, row.SOMMET_2])) in unique_pairs, axis=1)]

result = df.groupby('YEAR').apply(get_unique_pairs).reset_index(drop=True)
print(result)
```

which gives

```
  YEAR  SOMMET_1  SOMMET_2         R          X
0  2017  MTEZ5P71  MTEZIP71  0.395508   5.078320
1  2017  MTEZ5P71  RUEYRP71  0.395508   5.078320
2  2022  MTEZ5P71  RUEYRP71  0.006328  25.435898
3  2022  RUEYRP71  MTEZ5P71  0.006328  25.435898
4  2022  ARGIAP71  .HERN 71  1.180195  12.507539
```

Answer (score 0):

You can [`sort`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.sort.html) before [`drop_duplicates`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html):

```
import numpy as np

cols = ['SOMMET_1', 'SOMMET_2']
df[cols] = np.sort(df[cols])

out = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['YEAR']+cols)
```

*NB. this mutates the original `df`, if you don't want to, first copy  `tmp = df.copy()` and use `tmp` in place of `df`.*

Output:

```
   YEAR  SOMMET_1  SOMMET_2         R          X
0  2017  MTEZ5P71  MTEZIP71  0.395508   5.078320
1  2017  MTEZ5P71  RUEYRP71  0.395508   5.078320
2  2022  MTEZ5P71  RUEYRP71  0.006328  25.435898
4  2022  .HERN 71  ARGIAP71  1.180195  12.507539
```